# How to ask my co-author to put our paper on arXiv?

Tags: publications, research-process, mathematics, collaboration, arxiv

I am a math postdoc who defended his Ph.D. two years ago. I have been working on a project with some senior mathematician for 1.5 years. I also invited him to the university where I am affiliated for two weeks. We finished some preliminary versions of a paper, and then he told me he will send the complete version by June. After some time, he dropped an email to me that our technique works for a more general version which is why he was rewriting the paper. Then, I got another email from him that he was slow and asked me to extend something to a more general case. I sent him the extension, which was not complete as I was not not sure about some minor problems, but he hasn't replied to my email yet.

I told him some months ago that I am going to apply for some grant which is why we need to put the paper on arXiv, and he said "sure, I understand you". But, now, there is no news.

**Question**

I want to send an email and ask how the project is going on, but I am ashamed to ask as he does most of the project. On the other hand, I need to put this paper on arXiv because of the grant proposal. As I said, I want to send an email to him, but I am scared he tells me "what you did and why you expect to finish soon".

**Remark**

It is too late to finish the project myself as he changed most settings, so it takes a lot of time.

Comment: what impact will have on the grant comitee an arXiv paper instead of a paper that is mentioned as "under preparation"?

Comment: @EarlGrey: Paper published means referee(s) did not find errors, paper in arXiv means you see no errors, paper in preparation means "there might be fatal errors". See the difference?

Comment: "In preparation" sometimes means "will never be finished". I would guess that "in preparation" will count much less than preprint.

Comment: Ever heard about this thing called a phone and having a conversation with him about it? Talking helps.

Comment: @Oбжорoв That is my question. What I should tell him?

Comment: @Adam in your question you say you want to send an email to him. That is not talking to him. Talk to him and raise your concerns and try to find common ground to go forward. Emails often create more problems than they resolve. Talking is better.

Comment: @Oбжорoв ?He lives in a different country. That is why ?I should send an email to him

Comment: @Adam You cannot call someone who lives in a different country? Seriously?

Comment: @markvs what impact will have on the grant comitee an arXiv paper instead of a paper that is mentioned as "under preparation"?

Comment: @EarlGrey: A positive impact. ArXiv is much better (a publication would be even better).

Comment: @markvs better with respect to what?

Comment: With respect to possibility of getting the grant. If I get a proposal which lists papers in preparation, I automatically reject it,

Comment: @markvs it is a very hard filter, funnily enough coming from a mathematician and not from a bureaucrat.

Comment: @EarlGrey: When I am on a grant panel, I am a bureaucrat. And there are 12-13 others there too. The goal of the panel is to find out why the grant should **not** be given. Too many proposals.

Comment: @markvs I understand, but then it is a rule in your own specific discipline, it is not you rejecting something, it is a grant rule: not all the academia works like that.

Comment: @EarlGrey My discipline is indeed not the whole academia, just mathematics. But in every discipline the panel is searching for reasons to rejec:t. Why give them the reason? Unless it is explicitly written somewhere that this cannot be the reason. Then the panel director will interfere,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not going back to the very specific case, put that one in arXiv and then work with the needed time/effort toward the more general case? This way you put some pressure on him to finish the most general case, before someone else extend your arXiv paper.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What exactly I should tell him?

Comment: "Dear X., I am going to apply for some grant, I need to have a referrable proof that I am working on topic Y, so I will put a reduced version of the paper on arxiv, presenting the solution for the specific case.
Do you agree on being co-author?
Best regards, "

Comment: I agree this is the best solution in this situation

Comment: @EarlGrey : Isn't it rude to write the last sentence? Definitely, he is a co-author as he does the most things.

Comment: @EarlGrey : Do you think that he will tell me e "what you did and why you expect to finish soon"/

Comment: rude: maybe, you are welcome find a milder way to get confirmation about him being ok with the co-authorship.
About his questions: who cares, answer them honestly, you can be 100% sure or 100% unsure about finishing "soon", but without the grant finishing will be 100% sure much harder.

Answer (score 1):

“Hi, just a quick reminder, I was hoping to put a version of our paper on the arxiv by DATE, before I apply for GRANT. Any chance you think you might have a draft we could upload by then? If not, could we put up the previous version for now, just so I can refer to something publicly available in my proposal? We can always add the new version later. Thanks very much”

Comment: "could we put up the previous version for now," If uploaded to arXiv, it is up forever, not just *for now*.

Comment: Literally the next sentence: “We can always add the new version later.” People add preliminary versions all the time. Sometimes you have multiple drafts, with even significant rewrites. If it’s majorly different, they can even add it as a separate submission.

Answer (score -4):

Strictly speaking, if you are a co-author of the work, you are welcome to [submit it yourself](https://arxiv.org/help/authority#a-note-on-authorship-in-scholarly-works). However note that bell "cannot be unrung", so once it's announced it cannot be completely removed.

Comment: It's very important to have consent from all coauthors before doing this; you cannot just submit it yourself without their permission.

Comment: Important and ethical? Yes. Legally speaking? It's not required if you're a co-author of the work.

Comment: Curious what legal doctrine you are working under; I don't know that it is illegal anywhere, but I would be very hesitant to claim it's legal everywhere...

Comment: US Copyright Law. Under normal circumstances, any full author would have the legal authority to grant one of the available licenses in arXiv. In general, if you're an author of the work, legally speaking, you would have the authority to grant the license. 
Ethically? No, you need to have permission.

Comment: US copyright law tends not to matter outside the US.

Comment: While true, arXiv is based out of the US therefore only US Law is considered when making such decisions. It's the responsibility of the submitter to ensure compliance with local laws, however for the purposes of managing arXiv, only US law applies. 
It's a rather pedantic answer, but it's the governing principles behind what we do.

Comment: The real world is governed by far more than laws, because others can make decisions that affect your career based on their judgment of your actions. Submitting work without your coauthors' permission is a short ticket towards not having any coauthors, which is a short ticket towards not having a career.